# brand rebuses for you

Tags: rebus

I know you like rebuses, here are seven rebuses, each one is a brand to guess. Enjoy :)

[image]

Comment: Ha ha ha, I just remembered when I asked a brand-rebus and you @Flying_whale answered them all ^-^

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I had yours in mind when I decided to create this one :)

Comment: lol thanks, I think yours is much better though :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

> Metro + gold + win + May + year = **MGM**

2.

> French bucket + Japanese 2 = seau + ni = **Sony**

3.

> Peas in a V shape = **Peavey**

4.

> No Kia = **Nokia** (found by cpcodes)

5.

> D in doge = **Dodge** (found by cpcodes)

6.

> Gibbs' son = **Gibson** (found by QuantumTwinkie)

7.

> (Heinz + 00005 = Heine) + Ken = **Heineken**

Comment: this is indeed the good answer for 7 :)

Comment: 1 and 2 are correct too :)

Comment: Could you explain how you got #2? Also, I'm not clear on the last symbol in #1, but the rest of the answer makes sense - I kept thinking sub or subway or train for the first image and so missed that one entirely.

Comment: unfortunatly, this is not the answer I got in mind for 3, yours makes sense though. Your way of thinking is really close to give you the right answer, but maybe this brand is a bit less-known than the 6 others

Comment: @Flying_whale Author edited this answer.

Comment: 3 is probably now correct (I felt it looked more like a V than a U, so this seems better), but I have been assuming that the existence of the forks is relevant, so perhaps not.

Comment: yep, Peavey is the right answer :)  I will accept your answer, as you solved the majority of the rebuses ;)

Comment: For completeness, you have my permission to copy my answers into your post, and I would hope that QuantumTwinkie will allow the same.

Comment: Yup I will do the same :D

Answer (score 4):

4:

> Nokia

5:

> Dodge

Still working on the others

Comment: yep, good answer for 4 and 5 :)

Answer (score 4):

Is 6

> Gibson? Leroy Jethro Gibbs's son

Comment: yep, good answer for 6. damn guys you are faster than expected :)